# How do you sort a list of filepaths by the filename?

Tags: filenames, sort

I have the following list of files in a textfile named files.txt:

```
./themes/seven/images/list-item-rtl.png
./themes/seven/images/arrow-desc.png
./themes/seven/images/arrow-prev.png
./themes/seven/images/fc-rtl.png
./themes/seven/ie7.css
./xmlrpc.php
./MAINTAINERS.txt
./update.php
./README.txt
./COPYRIGHT.txt
./web.config
```

I want to sort them by just the filename (sort by the first characters after the last occurrence of the forward-slash). So the above would be output like so:

```
./COPYRIGHT.txt
./MAINTAINERS.txt
./README.txt
./themes/seven/images/arrow-desc.png
./themes/seven/images/arrow-prev.png
./themes/seven/images/fc-rtl.png
./themes/seven/ie7.css
./themes/seven/images/list-item-rtl.png
./update.php
./web.config
./xmlrpc.php
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '/' '{ printf "%s/%s\n", $NF, $0 }' files.txt | sort | cut -d '/' -f 2-
./COPYRIGHT.txt
./MAINTAINERS.txt
./README.txt
./themes/seven/images/arrow-desc.png
./themes/seven/images/arrow-prev.png
./themes/seven/images/fc-rtl.png
./themes/seven/ie7.css
./themes/seven/images/list-item-rtl.png
./update.php
./web.config
./xmlrpc.php
```

This prepends a copy the filename to the front of the line followed by a `/` character.  The filename is had by taking the last `/`-delimited field.  The last field is `$NF` in `awk`.

The output of the `awk` command is sorted.  This sorting will use the `/`-delimited field added to the front of the line.  `cut` is then used to remove the added `/`-delimited field.

This approach would work as long as no pathname contains a literal newline character.

There may also be an issue if any of the pathnames end with a `/` character (possibly the pathname of a directory).  These would yield an empty string in the sorting column.

See also: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (`gawk`) one my specify array traversals:

```
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"} 
           { a[$NF]=$0 }
           END { for ( i in a ) { print a[i] } }' files.txt
```

In that case: load data into array, indices are defined by the last `/`-separated field (i.e. filename), elements are the lines of the file. Then traverse array sorted by index value for the printing step.

---

Basic utils only:

```
paste <(rev files.txt | cut -d'/' -f 1 | rev) files.txt  | sort | cut -f2
```